# How do I get hardware information on Linux/Unix?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, system

How I can get hardware information from a Linux / Unix machine.
Is there a set of APIs?

I am trying to get information like:

- OS name.
- OS version.
- available network adapters.
- information on network adapters.
- all the installed software.

I am looking for an application which collects this information and show it in a nice format.
I have used something similar with the "system_profile" command line tool for Mac OS X. I 
was wondering if something similar is available for Linux as well.

Comment: There are many, many ways, from command line tools to kernel API calls. Unless you tell us what you're trying to do, any answers could only be guesswork.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you need a simple answer, use:

- `cat /proc/cpuinfo`
- `cat /proc/meminfo`
- `lspci`
- `lsusb`

and harvest any info you need from the output of these commands. (Note: the `cut` command may be your friend here if you are writing a shell script.)

Should you need more detail, add a `-v` switch to get verbose output from the `lspci` and `lsusb` commands.

If what you are looking for is a more feature-complete API, then use HAL, though that may be an overkill for what you are trying to build.

Comment: Or write some script in a nice scripting language to fetch and format the data the way you want. Don't forget to add ifconfig for network adapter infos.

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for a tool that show System Information, the GUI tool like [HardInfo](http://hardinfo.berlios.de/HomePage) would useful for you.

In Ubuntu, you can install HardInfo like this...

> sudo apt-get install hardinfo

Cheers

Answer (score 7):

There is a bash command lshw - list hardware

Comment: In some circumstances, lshw might not be available, but dmidecode, which provides similar information, often is (I'm thinking on VMware ESX hypervisors).

Comment: @Unicorn, can you be more specific about the hardware information you want to extract?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `hal`, the hardware abstraction layer.  It includes both some GUI commands, some tty commands (which can be used from shell programs), and library bindings for c and multiple other languages.

HAL is not really a standard part of "linux", but I think it is used by most modern distros.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo lshw`.
It's the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned API, try the [exec](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) family of commands for C. You can use them to execute these binaries that other people have mentioned. To create a robust/flexible solution you will probably also have to leverage the Unix fork() commands. You will also have to develop a mechanism for capturing the output spewed by these utilities. Look into Unix pipes for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inxi](https://github.com/smxi/inxi) which provide all hardware  information including cpu temperature and so on.

Install on Red Hat based OS
`sudo dnf install inixi`

Install on Debian based OS
`apt-get install inxi`